# Meaning of "babies were made that carried"?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "babies were made that carried" in the following sentence,

**

> To treat maternal infertility, babies ***were made that carried*** genetic
> information from 3 humans.

**

(Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAhjPd4uNFY )

?

Does "babies were made that carried genetic information" mean "babies were made and babies were carried genetic information" ?

Does "that" in the sentence mean "and babies were" ?
Is "that" a relative pronoun with babies as an antecedent? If so, why is the antecedent(babies) not placed right before the relative pronoun?

[image]

Comment: Can you please link to a specific time in the video? Saying "babies were made" sounds very [**Frankenstein**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victor_Frankenstein). Usually "let's make a baby" is said in private between friends.

Comment: Presumably they were 'test tube' babies. The babies _carried_ (had in their chromosomes) genetic information from three people.

Comment: I remember being told, aged 9, how babies were made. It seems that I am in need of updating.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey what I was told is true: the postman brought the bits and I was put together in the kitchen.

Comment: @Weather Vane//  2: 51 in (Source: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jAhjPd4uNFY )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "normal" order would be

> babies that carried genetic information from 3 humans were made.

But because the relative clause is long and the predicate ("were made") is short the writer has [extraposed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition) the relative clause for clarity.